# Tensor-hom adjunction for $\mathcal{D}$-modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules

Let $X$ be a smooth equidimensional scheme over $\mathbb{C}$. Given two left $\mathcal{D}_X$-modules $M$ and $N$, we endow their tensor product (as $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules) $M\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} N$ with a left $\mathcal{D}_X$-module structure via the Leibniz rule.

While I think that abstract nonsense should imply that this tensor product has a right-adjoint (I didn't verify it though), I wonder if it has a simple definition. (Perhaps it is $\omega_X^\vee \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\underline{\hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X}(M,N)$?) Moreover, just to confirm, is this the internal hom which appears in the six-functor formalism for $\mathcal{D}$-modules?